# Show there are a pair of sentences where the first says the second is provable and the second says the first is unprovable

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Given $B_1(y)$ and $B_2(y)$ in the language of arithmetic, show there are sentences $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that:

$$\vdash_Q G_1 \leftrightarrow B_2(\ulcorner G_2 \urcorner)$$

$$\vdash_Q G_2 \leftrightarrow B_1(\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about it, but I think we must start with [Gödel's sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) $G$ :

> For each consistent formal theory $Q$ having the required small amount of number theory, the corresponding Gödel sentence $G$ asserts : "$G$ cannot be proved within the theory $Q$".

Let $G_1 := \lnot G$.

$G_1$ asserts : "$G$ **is** provable in $Q$".

Thus :

> $G_1$ iff $\exists x Pf(x, \ulcorner G \urcorner)$, where $Pf$ is the predicate formalizing the fact that $x$ is the Gödel's number of a proof in $Q$ of the formula with Gödel's number $\ulcorner G \urcorner$ [see Elliott Mendelson, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (4th ed - 1997), page 198].

The above fact is provable in $Q$; thus :

> $\vdash_Q G_1 \leftrightarrow \exists x Pf(x, \ulcorner G \urcorner)$.

Now, let $G_2 := \lnot G_1$. Thus, $G_2$ is the original Gödel's sentence $G$. So, we may replace $\ulcorner G \urcorner$ with $\ulcorner G_2 \urcorner$ to get :

> $\vdash_Q G_1 \leftrightarrow \exists x Pf(x, \ulcorner G_2 \urcorner)$.

Up to now, we have found $B_2(x)$ such that :

> > $\vdash_Q G_1 \leftrightarrow B_2(\ulcorner G_2 \urcorner)$.

Gödel's Theorem "formalized" in Q amount to :

> $\vdash_Q G \leftrightarrow \lnot \exists x Pf(x, \ulcorner G \urcorner)$.

Using $Neg$, the *negation* function [see Mendelson, page 196], we have that $\ulcorner G \urcorner = Neg(\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner)$; thus, being $G_2$ and $G$ the "same formula" :

> $\vdash_Q G_2 \leftrightarrow \lnot \exists x Pf(x, Neg(\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner))$.

Thus, we have $B_1$ such that :

> > $\vdash_Q G_2 \leftrightarrow B_1(\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner)$.

---

*Added : April, 8*

As per comment of Peter Smith above, this answer does not address the original question, which ask for $B_1$ and $B_2$ arbitrary wffs with one free variable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question as I understand it, which has $B_1$ and $B_2$ *arbitrary* wffs with one free variable. What is being sought seems to be a proof of a general variant of the diagonalization lemma, which can then be applied to the probability predicate and its negation to solve the title problem.

Comment: Can this answer be modified to answer the original question?

Comment: @user1038665 - I think not; you must use the other one, i.e.reproduce the proof of the Diagonal Lemma using the two formulas $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: Can you show how that is done for the first sentence in the pair? I'm not sure how to generalize with $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: Also, what do the $B$'s denote here? What kind of functions are they?

Comment: @user1038665 - in this answer, which does not give us the correct solution for the exercise, we have "constructed" the formula $B_2(y) := ∃xPf(x,y)$, and $B_1(y) := \lnot ∃xPf(x,y)$.

Comment: How is this done correctly, then? It seems like we obtained the result that was necessary.

Comment: @user1038665 - see Peter Smith's comment : I've "manufactured" two formulas $B_1$ and $B_2$ which have the said property; but the problem ask for $B_1$ and $B_2$ whatever. You have to use the *Hint* and see BBJ, page 221 : instead of considering the sentence $G := ∃x(x = a \land ∃y(Diag(x,y) \land B(y)))$ we have to use the "double diagonal" $E_1$ and $E_2$ in the same way.

Comment: That's quite confusing!

Comment: @user1038665 - for me also ! What is the source of the question's title ?: "Show there are a pair of sentences where the first says the second is provable and the second says the first is unprovable". The *Diagonal Lemma* (page 221) says that "for any formula $B(y)$ of $T$ there is a sentence $G$ such that $\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow B(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$. Godel's theorem is a "special case" of this *Lemma*, when the formula $B(y)$ is the "provability predicate" $Pf$; but for a formula $B(y)$ whatever, the corresponding $G$ does not necessarly "speaks of" provability or unprovability.

Comment: @user1038665 - I've made an addition to the answer, but I'm still in trouble to complete the proof.

Answer (score 2):

See George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, *Computability and Logic* (5th ed - 2007), Problem 17.3, page 229.

We have to follow the hints in the website of the book :

> Imitate the proof of the Diagonal Lemma [see BBJ, page 221], beginning as follows:
>
> For formulas $E_1(x, y)$ and $E_2(x, y)$ with code numbers $e_1$ and $e_2$, let the first and second double diagonals be :
>
> $\exists x \exists y (x = e_1 \land y = e_2 \land E_1(x, y))$, logically equivalent to $E_1(e_1, e_2)$
>
> and
>
> $\exists x \exists y (x = e_1 \land y = e_2 \land E_2(x, y))$, logically equivalent to $E_2(e_1, e_2)$.

*Added - April, 18*

I'm still not sure, but I think we need a "trick" in order to use the formulas of the *Hint*.

Starting from $B_1(x)$ and $B_2(x)$ whatever, let :

> $E_1(x,y) := B_2(y) \land x = x$
>
> $E_2(x,y) := B_1(x) \land y = y$.

Clearly : $\forall y(E_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow B_2(x))$ and $\forall x(E_2(x,y) \leftrightarrow B_1(y))$.

Now we consider $E_1(x,y)$ and $E_2(x,y)$ formulas.

Let $su (w, x_1, x_2)$ the function subst whose value at $\overline a, \overline b_1, \overline b_2$ is the G-number of the result of substituting respectively the numerals $\overline b_1, \overline b_2$ for the variables $x_1, x_2$ in the formula with G-number $\overline a$ [see the **generalized diagnal lemma** in George Boolos, *The Logic of Provability* (1993), page 53].

Let $\overline k_i$, be the G-number of :

$E_i(su(x_1, x_1, x_2), su(x_2, x_1, x_2))$

and let $G_i$ be the formula

$E_i(su(\overline k_1, \overline k_1, \overline k_2), su(\overline k_2, \overline k_1, \overline k_2))$.

The result of respectively substituting the numerals $\overline k_1, \overline k_2$ for the variables $x_1, x_2$ in the formula with G-number $\overline k_i$, i.e., in the formula

$E_i(su (x_1, x_1, x_2), su(x_2, x_1, x_2))$

is the formula $G_i$ and therefore subst($\overline k_i, \overline k_1, \overline k_2$) = the G-number of $G_i$.

Therefore, in $Q$ we can prove $su(\overline k_i, \overline k_1, \overline k_2) = \ulcorner G_i \urcorner$.

But by "construction", we have :

> $\vdash_Q G_1 \leftrightarrow E_1 (\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner,\ulcorner G_2 \urcorner)$,

and $\vdash \forall y(E_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow B_2(y))$;

thus :

> > $\vdash_Q G_1 \leftrightarrow B_2(\ulcorner G_2 \urcorner)$.

In the same way :

> $\vdash_Q G_2 \leftrightarrow E_2 (\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner,\ulcorner G_2 \urcorner) \leftrightarrow B_1(\ulcorner G_1 \urcorner)$.